# Run header under each group of days

Tags: excel, vba, header

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QmvHk.jpg)Flight Schedule

[[image: Flight Schedule Complete]

I have a flight schedule consisting for 6 columns. On the image you see you can only see four, those are cut from a central database. The last 2 columns "SEATS" and "REMARKS" will be manually put it. I've got the coding for the four which I have inserted at the bottom of the rows, which in-fact they would serve as Headers for the next day. I'm looking how to make these headers which i managed through VBA to after the last data for the last day posted on the worksheet. I would like these to appear at the end of each day.The second part is for the last two columns how can I anchor them to the other columns so they will appear on the same row as the others.

```
Sub Headers()
Dim lastrow As Long
lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 2
ActiveSheet.Cells(lastrow, "B").Value = "FLIGHT #"

lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row + 2
ActiveSheet.Cells(lastrow, "C").Value = "A/C TYPE"

lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row + 2
ActiveSheet.Cells(lastrow, "D").Value = "ROLL CALL"

lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row + 2
ActiveSheet.Cells(lastrow, "E").Value = "SEAT RELEASE"

lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row + 2
ActiveSheet.Cells(lastrow, "F").Value = "REMARKS"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Try,

```
Sub test()

    Dim rngDB As Range
    Dim rng2 As Range
    Dim rng As Range, Target As Range
    Dim a As Variant, b As Variant
    Dim myDate As Date
    Dim n As Long
    
    Set rngDB = Range("b1", Range("d" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    
    Set rngDB = rngDB.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
    rngDB.EntireRow.Insert
    Set rng2 = rngDB.Offset(, 2)
    
    a = Array("FLIGHT #", "A/C TYPE", "ROLL CALL")
    b = Array("", "SEAT RELEASE", "REMARKS")

    With rng2
        .Value = b
        .Font.Size = 12
        .Font.Name = "Times New Roman"
        .Font.Bold = True
        .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlContinuous '<~~cell's botton lines style
        .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).Weight = xlMedium
    End With

    With rngDB
        .Value = a
        .Font.Size = 12
        .Font.Name = "Times New Roman"
        .Font.Bold = True
        .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlContinuous '<~~cell's botton lines style
        .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).Weight = xlMedium
    End With

    myDate = Date
    n = Date - DateSerial(Year(Date), 1, 0)
    For Each rng In rngDB.Areas
        Set Target = rng.Range("a1").Offset(, -1)
        Target = UCase(Format(myDate, "dddd mmmm d") & " (" & n & ")")
        myDate = myDate + 1
        n = n + 1
    Next rng
    With rngDB.Offset(, -1)
         .Font.Size = 12
        .Font.Name = "Times New Roman"
        .Font.Bold = True
        .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlContinuous '<~~cell's botton lines style
        .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).Weight = xlMedium
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Comment: that works great, how would I get a blank row inserted before each header? Additionally, I've already have a code for the font for the worksheet, but for these headings I want them bold, size 12, Times New Roman and a solid unbroken bold line under all headings in Column B through Column F. Thank you

Comment: @SheridanWhiteside, i edited answer.  'solid unbroken bold line'  is Character line?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help/work on this. I really appreciate the results. I would still like a space before the header after the first date. Regarding Column A I hope to use the formula NOW with the brackets, but somehow have it worked in the formula in the same format minus the year and commas. Then in brackets next to the date have the last three of the Julian date and that formula would be TODAY()-DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),1,0). The result would be SATURDAY OCTOBER 17 (290). The top row of headers would be the current date, and next day would see everything increase by one and so on.

Comment: @SheridanWhiteside, I don't understand your explanation.

Comment: Sorry about that last message. I was looking for guidance in adding a header for Column A as to whether or not a separate VBA would be need or just rolled into the one you provided. The first date in Column A would be in the format mentioned in the previous message and the first header in Column A would have the current date and the following headers in Column A a day would be added and a day added to the Julian Date (Just the last three days). Also if we insert a space between the last data in the columns and header would be great. Thank you for your patience and help.

Comment: @SheridanWhiteside, It will make sense to insert the results you want into an image.

Comment: Okay I added it, I hope you can see it. Lastly, how hard would it be to show if there were no flights to have a comment like the one seen that way no days will be skipped. I apologize for all of this. I have about a dozen micros now. thank you again.

Comment: That works perfectly, Thank you. The one concern I may have are those circumstances when there are no flights. for I think the dates will be off. As shown in the image I posted last night can I have something like "***NO FLIGHTS SCHEDULED***)?

Comment: @SheridanWhiteside,What you asked first and what was added now should have a completely different solution. Since the initial solution was simple, a simple solution was proposed, but the added question would require another solution. For example, you need to know the relationship between the date and time data in column d and the header in column a, but the people who answer here cannot know the correlation between your data. That's where judgment is your domain, and the answer I've presented is without consideration of empty dates.

Comment: I understand, I thought that would be a whole different VBA. You've provided so much already, and you described it perfectly regarding relationship for Column A and Column B. I cannot thank you enough for your help.

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub Headers()
Dim lastrow As Long
lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

With ActiveSheet
    For i = 1 To lastrow
        If ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1) = "" Then
            .Cells(i, 2) = "FLIGHT #"
            .Cells(i, 3) = "A/C TYPE"
            .Cells(i, 4) = "ROLL CALL"
            .Cells(i, 5) = "SEAT RELEASE"
            .Cells(i, 6) = "REMARKS"
        End If
    Next
End With

End Sub
```

and below code insert row and then add title

```
Sub Headers()
Dim lastrow As Long
lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

With ActiveSheet
    For i = 1 To lastrow
        If ActiveSheet.Cells(i, "B") = "" Then
            .Rows(i).Insert
            .Cells(i + 1, "B") = "FLIGHT #"
            .Cells(i + 1, "C") = "A/C TYPE"
            .Cells(i + 1, "D") = "ROLL CALL"
            .Cells(i + 1, "E") = "SEAT RELEASE"
            .Cells(i + 1, "F") = "REMARKS"
        End If
    Next
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: That is brilliant, I would like to use the second one. I did notice if I have numerous dates it will not quite reach the bottom or get all the dates? In addition I already have a code to address the font for the worksheet, but for these specific header I want to make them 12 bold and Times New Roman and if possible one solid thick bold  line to run across from Column A to Column F uninterrupted. Thank you so much!

Comment: that's wonderful, I tweaked it just so the last two column headers show up in bold. I would still like it to insert a blank row before the headers starting after the sets of dates.